# How to Pass value in text box control through Cefsharp

Tags: javascript, cefsharp

I am working on an Application in which I have to parse the WebApplication Through Cefsharp code , I Use below code to insert value

Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('username').value='" + name + "'");                   Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('password').value='" + passwd + "'");
using this code the username and password is display in text boxes
but the website input text box have validation of "ng-untouched" because of this i am not able to enter inside the website. kindly suggest

Comment: You can always remove the validation.

Comment: Or change it in code so that it's valid.